# Type annotations needed for none variant - ergonomics

Tags: rust, ergonomics

I have a struct with a field 'payload' of `Option<T>` where T can be one of several primitive integer types. Like so:

```rust
pub struct Request<T: MyIntTrait> {
    pub cmd: Cmd,
    pub payload: Option<T>,
    a bunch of other fields...
}
```

When instantiating this struct with None as its payload obviously type annotations are needed:

```rust
let req: Request<u8> = Request { cmd: Cmd::Get, payload: None, ...}
```

or like this:

```rust
let req = Request { cmd: Cmd::Get, payload: None::<u8>, ...}
```

This makes for a very unergonomic api that is counterintuitive to use.
Has anybody got an idea how to get around this or will I just have to live with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the `T` can be inferred somewhere else, you have to specify it somehow.  You could specify a default for the type argument, which may be sufficient in your case:

```
pub struct Request<T: MyIntTrait = u8>
```

Comment: Perfect! Didn't know it's possible to set a default for a type parameter. This solves my problem. Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't disable inference anywhere, and this is effectively unuseful because you will still need to specify the type as `Request` (`let x: Request = Request { ... }`), only a minor difference, or `let x = Request::<> { ... }`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Yeah, true. I noticed as well. But at least one doesn't have to specify the type of "None" anymore which at least to me seems very counterintuitive.

Comment: @PaulSimon I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Well, I presented just a simplified example to demonstrate the problem. In my real code there is another const generic parameter corresponding to the size of T. Then I needed to write ```let req: Request<u16, 2> = Request { payload: None, ... } ```. I just found that to be a bit awkward - a None value of type u16 and size 2...

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Hmm, there was an example I constructed where inference appeared to not work correctly when I extracted a variable.  I'm wondering now if it was a spurious error from my IDE because I can no longer duplicate it.